# É correta a pronúncia do R-RR no português europeu como em espanhol?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia

Eu acho que há algumas pessoas que pronunciam o R como em espanhol (vibrante alveolar)  no português europeu, mas são muito poucas e é usual a pronúncia como uma vibrante uvular. Eu estou agora a morar em Portugal e pronúncio o R como na minha língua materna (o espanhol) e não sei se faço bem. Especificamente é nos casos onde o R é inicial ou doble: **r**ato, **r**ápido, ca**rr**o, bu**rr**o, etc.

Obrigado pelas respostas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hoje em dia, a pronúncia do fonema [/ʀ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill) como [[r]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_trills) é dialetal, dado que não ocorre na língua-padrão de Portugal, conforme diz esta resposta do [Ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-a-pronuncia-do-r/29585), citando a gramática de Maria Mateus e outras:

> A consoante uvular representada por [R] é a vibrante que se encontra no dialecto-padrão do português europeu [aqui entendida como o dialeto de Lisboa ou Coimbra], em que a sua produção implica a acção da úvula [nota: [Pedro Martins](https://web.archive.org/web/20201009193924/https://sigarra.up.pt/flup/pt/pub_geral.show_file?pi_doc_id=14819) indica que a realização mais comum não é vibrante, mas sim [[ʁ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative#cite_note-30)]. Em alguns dialectos existe uma variante dental, a vibrante múltipla que se representa por [r].

Essa resposta aponta também genericamente para o norte do país como a região em que [r] é usado, [citanto esta outra resposta](http://velho.ciberduvidas.pt/pergunta.php?id=16894). [Pedro Martins](https://web.archive.org/web/20201009193924/https://sigarra.up.pt/flup/pt/pub_geral.show_file?pi_doc_id=14819) atesta-o em três zonas do norte e numa outra perto de Faro (fig. 4, p. 519).

Se vale a pena o esforço de adaptação agora é contigo; não haverá certamente dificuldade de compreensão (afinal de contas, em Setúbal pronuncia-se /ʀ/ e /ɾ/ da mesma forma e a gente percebe-os), mas é uma pronúncia que em Lisboa será sentida, no mínimo, como marcadamente dialetal.

Comment: A wikipédia diz que em Portugal também se pronuncia como fricatica uvular. Ouve aqui [carro no Forvo](http://pt.forvo.com/word/carro/#pt): o aimae e o cimbalino paracem fazê-lo. Para aí 1% dos setubalenses pronuncia *caro* e *carro* da mesma maneira. Mas o moral da história mantém-se. Eu conheço um, e compreendo-o bem.

Comment: Já o mesmo aimae parece pronuncia [rato](http://pt.forvo.com/word/rato/#pt) mais como vibrante. Mas escuta o paperless: aquilo é fricativa uvular ou mesmo velar.

Comment: @Jacinto Isto dava pano para mangas. Pela minha parte, consigo perceber que definitivamente 1) não uso uma vibrante e 2) é sonora. Definitivamente não diria _rato_ como o aimae. Quanto ao ponto de articulação parece mais posterior que o /g/ e o /k/, por isso deve ser [ʁ], que de resto parece ser de longe a realização mais comum, segundo [este artigo](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pedro_Tiago_Martins/publication/259821534_As_Realizaes_Fonticas_de_R_em_portugus_europeu_anlise_de_um_corpus_dialetal_e_implicaes_no_sistema_fonolgico/links/0a85e52e03715374cd000000.pdf).