# About the pronunciation "r" in Portuguese

Tags: pronúncia

About the pronunciation "r" in Portuguese.

Ex: rua, the "r" is pronounced like "h" or "r" (trilled)

Comment: What is the question? Make sure one of the sentences is an actual question, so that it's clear hat you are asking.

Comment: No, the r is not trilled,

Comment: In Portugal, it _can_ be trilled but generally isn't; see https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/%c3%89-correta-a-pron%c3%bancia-do-r-rr-no-portugu%c3%aas-europeu-como-em-espanhol

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the pronunciation of a letter in a given word, it's simplest to look it up in a dictionary with audio and/or phonetic transcription (or even google "*word* Portuguese pronunciation" without quotes). For instance, [Infopédia for foreigners](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/portugues-estrangeiros/rua) provides an audio and phonetic transcription (ˈʀuɐ — you'd of course have to familiarize yourself with the [phonetic alphabet](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/cpp/acessibilidade/capitulo2_1.html) used by your source).

As for the "r" in "rua", I pronounce it more like the "h" in "high". Now, if this is just a random example and you're actually interested in learning pronunciation in Portuguese in general, it's best to go through some appropriate learning material — and come back to us for concrete questions.

Comment: You pronounce "high" as "rái", stafusa? To me, this does not sound like the correct sound for the h: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_trill

Comment: But the first half of the answer is :chef's kiss: top quality, with even a link with audio! :)

Comment: @ANeves Thanks. Yes, I pronounce "high" as "rái" — _but_ my "r" in "rái" has no vibration, i.e., my "rua" is also not like the pronunciation in the linked audio, but smoother, similar to the ones by "eumesmo" (not me :-)), "nebralgia" or "fhufnagel" in [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/rua/#pt). That said, it's certainly also true that my pronunciation in English is not perfect. :)

Comment: Ah! I pronounce "rua" like cimbalino (not me! :-)), I guess that's where the confusion comes from. Yeah, my English is pretty good as well but I also find myself making funny mistakes - I won't throw stones! My two favourites are having confused roster with rooster, and having used mistress (illegitimate lover) thinking I was using mistress (master-ess). :D

Comment: pronunciation is always a complicated subject when learning a new language, the answer will differ depending on what accent we're talking about. the R is a particularly difficult letter to answer, it is IMHO the letter that changes the most depending on the accent

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to the H pronunciation from Human.

Comment: "Hoover" could be even better, as "hoo" sounds quite similar to the Portuguese "ru".